# Why can't I create a PHP header from a server variable?

Tags: php

For some reason, I can't include a custom PHP $server variable inside of a header function. PHP doesn't acknowledge it's existence even though I can print it to console. Here are the steps I'm taking.

I have a header in my response which I fetch with

```
 $domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_DOMAIN"];
 // print_r($domain);
 // prints: stackoverflow.com
```

Next, I join the $domain variable with 'https://' and create a header.

```
 $var = 'https://' . $domain;
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $var);
```

However - I get a console error saying:

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'https://'.
```

It's like the $domain variable is empty even though it's set and can be printed to console. If I change the domain variable to a string like 'stackoverflow.com' then everything works perfectly.

```
 $domain = 'stackoverflow.com'.
```

I don't understand what could be the issue if both possibilities of the $domain variable return strings, are not empty, encoded with ASCII and print to screen if I run a print_r() function with them.

Any clues on what to troubleshoot?

Comment: obviously you have no value in `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_DOMAIN"]` why you trying get needed value from it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding quotes

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " ."'". $var ."'");
```